# Change Oracle Apex region grid column with dynamic action

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

is there any way to change Oracle Apex region with dynamic action. I mean when i click a button, i execute dynamic action to change column order of a region or to change grid column width of a region. Lets say i have two region : regionA and RegionB. What i need to do is place RegionA side by side (not in a new row), so i have to place it in column order column1 and column 2, but then i need to hide RegionA and display RegionB in full screen, so the only way is dynamically change regionB to column 1 because i dont want regionB display in half of the screen.

Any clue would be appreciate. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnaly, I never use columns in Oracle Apex. I had too much problem with it in last releases (especially 3.2)... I was forced to build a new custom template with custom region positions (because at the time apex was using `<table>` elements for the page layout... I used only `<div>` elements + CSS).

In your case, if you need region A and region B side by side, I would create the two regions in the same region position and same column, and then simply apply `float:left` to the two regions (add `style="float:left"` in the region attributes).

So when you will hide one of them, the other one will fill the page width (you may need some more CSS of course).

Then give a static id to the two regions, then from JavaScript/Jquery you can show/hide them easily using `$('#your_region_id').hide();` and `$('#your_region_id').show();`.

I use it a lot and it works like a charm.

Comment: what about the column size? how to change it dynamically?

Comment: You are using columns finally ? If yes simply use _Column Attributes_ to set a width. But I repeat for me the best way is to create two regions that are using a `<div>` based template. Then set region 1 attributes to `float:left;width:50%;` and region 2 to `float:right;width:50%;`. Change width to your needs, and of course you can easily change it dynamically using JavaScript/Jquery. For me it does the job :)